# Categorization of C-Factor on the basis of NDVI values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I tried to calculate the C-factor using NDVI values in Google Earth Engine. I have the following conditions for calculating the c-Factor.

for NDVI<0, c-factor =0

for 0<NDVI<0.75, c-factor= -1.328* NDVI+1

for NDVI>0.75, c-factor =0.

I'm not getting the which condition to apply, please help me get it done.

```
var image= ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09GA_006_NDVI')
             .filterBounds(Dehradun)
             .select('NDVI')
             .filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')


var C_factor= image.map (function (image) {
  
      var cmap = image.expression(
        '-1.328*nd + 1', {
        'nd': image.select('NDVI')
        }).rename('cmap');
      
      return image.addBands(cmap)
    })

print('C_factor',C_factor)
```

link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/ccebd50aa5c94ff1fba93d5be3a3d150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions could be placed as follow (there are other alternatives):

```
var C_factor= image.map (function (image) {

  var cmap = image.select('NDVI')
                  .where(image.lt(0), 0)
                  .where(image.gte(0).and(image.lte(0.75)), image.expression('-1.328*nd + 1', {
                                                                             'nd': image.select('NDVI')
                                                                             }))
                  .where(image.gt(0.75), 0)
                  .rename('cmap');
  
  return image.addBands(cmap);

  
});
```

As your assets are not shareable, I employed an arbitrary area for Dehradun in following script:

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/3b80560101e96f1217e0d29a20c250f5

I used the Inspector Tab to explore some data and the function seems to work as expected.